# How to I make a text box update its text each time the bound field is updated?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am updating data with a button in Microsoft Access. Once the button is clicked the user has to select a folder. When the folder is selected, a query executes to put the folder name into a table. I've got the query executing fine and the data is being inserted correctly. My problem is now I want a text box to get the folder name from the table and display it. I got the text box bound to a field, but it isn't updating the text in the text box. How to I make a text box update its text each time the bound field is updated?

Here's the code I made:

```
 Dim sql As String

 sql = "UPDATE tableName SET FolderName = '" & folderNameVariable & "' " & _
        "WHERE tableName.tableID= " & Me.tableID

 CurrentProject.Connection.Execute sql
 'FolderName is the text box name
 Me.FolderName.Requery
 Me.Repaint
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace `Me.FolderName.Requery` by `Me.Requery`. 
`Me.Repaint` not required here.